Here Im having data table on website but I dont know why it is showing me word array on webite
Im trying to find why it is showing word "Array" on my webpage and also I dont know from where it is coming? also Im trying to find from where it is coming Here is the link below.
https://stagenet.newmacleanpower.com/product-category/hardware/adss-hardware/
I tried using Inspect element but it all in vain.

You need to provide the code you're using to display the page - it's not enough to link to the page, we need to see the PHP template code before there's any way to help you. Update your question, and add the PHP code that generates that table wrapped in the appropriate code tags so it's readable.

The cause of the issue is that you echo an array most probably.
find the table codes in your codes, and fix it there. you can also share the code of that page so we can help you on that.
